# React app does not set json data to a state, but can console.log set data

Tags: reactjs

This is my code, i really need some help here because i don't understand why this is happening. I have tried this, i was 90% sure that it will work but it didn't.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState();
  const APP_ID = 
  const APP_KEY = 

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSearch(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${search}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}&from=0&to=3&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setResult(data));
    console.log(result);

    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Search foods</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="" value={search} onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: what is the issue you are having ?

Comment: @BARNOWL the issue is when i console.log(result) i get an empty string instead of a json, but when i do console.log(data) i recive the json in the console.

Comment: i made this on codesandbox, if you provide APP ID, or APP Key i can dig deeper, but i provided an answer, let me know if helps.

Comment: @BARNOWL Here, APP_ID="a1dc0018", APP_KEY="e9980bac391d3a9e030265d236f4001e". By the way, i tried the solution, and it didn't work. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: check the updated answer, and let me know. It's working for me

Comment: @BARNOWL it is actually working, but the first time i search i get a null, then i get the result, how can i fix this? thanks.

Comment: let me debug further

Comment: @BARNOWL probably because the search entry isn't recived yet, so firstly it gives me a null, but the second time when the function runs, the data is already recived and it returns me the json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your `result` state is updated but it can not be viewed immediately. If you add another button as follow after the form, you can view the data:

```
<button onClick={() => console.log(result)}>View Data</button>
```

What I guess happened here is, after submitting the form, components rendered again and during the next rendering, state updated. So it can't be viewed immediately.

Comment: This works, but i would want it to work with the same button, can you please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Few days ago I also tried to do the same. Validating form inside `handleSubmit` and that cost a day. Then I find this, according to react's [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#fully-fledged-solutions) for full fledged solution, use [Formik](https://formik.org/).

Comment: Currently I'm using Formik and I can assure you from my personal experience that its really a pleasing experience to use Formik!